# Reading HTTP Header Python

Tags: python, sockets, http

I've written a very basic web server in python that can take in requests and spew data back to the client. But my issue is reading the HTTP request, is there a library in python for easily breaking down the HTTP header? Because I'd rather not use my clunky code just for retrieving the GET data.

Comment: [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) is one that can probably help you

Answer (score 1):

You can use Requests module to get all the details from HTTP request, here is a small example below from the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.headers['content-type']
'application/json; charset=utf8'
>>> r.encoding
'utf-8'
>>> r.text
u'{"type":"User"...'
>>> r.json()
{u'private_gists': 419, u'total_private_repos': 77, ...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you get **just** the response headers using the requests library (implementation in Python3):

```
import requests

url = "https://www.google.com"
response = requests.head(url)
print(response.headers) # prints the entire header as a dictionary
print(response.headers["Content-Length"]) # prints a specific section of the dictionary
```

It's important to use .head() instead of .get() otherwise you will retrieve the whole file/page.

If you wish to retrieve a URL that requires authentication you can replace the above `response` with this:

```
response = requests.head(url, auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
```